# How to export data from orc file format table into normal text file format table?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have hive table which is ORC file format table with bucketing. I have huge data in that table. Now I want to move data into new table which normal text format table.
I am running below query.

```
insert into table db_name.tab_name PARTITION (process_name,year, month)  
select intcentralstagingdataid, intpullrunid,intdynamicrunid,bintcrawlingid,   
nvcrcrawlingtimestamp, nvcrcrawlingstatus, nvcrsupplier, nvcrnumberofnights,  
nvcrcheckindate, nvcrcheckoutdate, nvcrtotalpricewithtax, nvcrpointofsale,   
nvcrcity, nvcrcountry, nvcrhotelname, nvcrnumberofadults, nvcrdailyrate,     
nvcrcurrency, nvcrtax, nvcrroomtype, nvcrsupplierhotel, nvcrstarrating, 
nvcravailabilitystatus, nvcrboardtype, nvcrpromotion, 
nvcrpromotiondescription, nvcrisb2b, nvcrpropertydescription, nvcrpostcode, 
nvcrb2bhotelcode, nvcrdirectpayement, nvcrcancellationpolicy, 
nvcrcustomerreviewsrating, nvcrcustomerreviewcomments, nvcrhotelfacilities, 
nvcrflexprice, nvcrnonflexprice, nvcrflexcurrency, nvcrnonflexcurrency, 
nvcrflexpricecapturedpage, nvcrnonflexpricecapturedpage, 
nvcrcountryproxyused, dtminsertedon, nvcrroomcode, dtmrecord_date, 
process_name, year, month 
from  db_name.tab_name 
where process_name='<Condition>' AND year=<Condition> AND month=<Condition>;
```

But after executing this query I am getting this issue:

```
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1446452616907_0014_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1446452616907_0014_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.Run
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:138)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:324)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:176)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:163)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:294)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:163)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorMapOperator.process(VectorMapOperator.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:83)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating 'Hotels4U'
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorSelectOperator.processOp(VectorSelectOperator.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorMapOperator.process(VectorMapOperator.java:45)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 48
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.expressions.ConstantVectorExpression.evaluateBytes(ConstantVectorExpression.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.expressions.ConstantVectorExpression.evaluate(ConstantVectorExpression.java:156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorSelectOperator.processOp(VectorSelectOperator.java:124)
        ... 21 more
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:138)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:324)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:176)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:163)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:294)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:163)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorMapOperator.process(VectorMapOperator.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:83)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating 'Hotels4U'
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorSelectOperator.processOp(VectorSelectOperator.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorMapOperator.process(VectorMapOperator.java:45)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 48
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.expressions.ConstantVectorExpression.evaluateBytes(ConstantVectorExpression.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.expressions.ConstantVectorExpression.evaluate(ConstantVectorExpression.java:156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorSelectOperator.processOp(VectorSelectOperator.java:124)
        ... 21 more
], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:138)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:324)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:176)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
```

have any idea, how to resolve it?

Comment: What is 'Hotels4U', as thats seen in the stack trace **Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating 'Hotels4U'**